How is voltage drop across a resistor, that is drop in potential difference due to the resistor, is determined by Ohm's law?
In the famous equation V = IR of Ohm's law, V is the potential difference present between two points and I is the strength of electric current and R is the resistance of the resistor.
But the same equation is also applied to determine the drop in potential difference due to the resistor.
How is this justified? How can V mean both the potential difference present between the ends of the resistor and also at the same time the drop in potential difference between the same ends of the resistor?
Ex: If 'r' is the internal resistance of the battery and the strength of the current is I, then the loss in potential difference due to the internal resistance of the battery is given by I.r.


How can $V$ mean both the potential difference present between the ends of the resistor and also at the same time the drop in potential difference between the same ends of the resistor ?

Normally we would say that $V$ is the drop in potential (not drop in potential difference) across the resistor.
It is true that potentials are always measured relative to some baseline - typically we define anything that is "earthed" to be $0$ volts. So you could say that the potential that is measured at any one point in a circuit is actually a potential difference. But that would be confusing because then the potential difference between two points in a circuit then becomes a difference of differences.
So usually we say that what we measure at one point in a circuit is a potential, and what we measure between two points is a potential difference.

If the internal resistance of the galvanic cell is r and the strength of the current passing through the galvanic cell is I, then drop in voltage due to the internal resistance is given by I.r according to Ohm's law. How is this justified?

@Learner A battery such as a galvanic cell acts as if it is a ideal voltage source of voltage $V$ in series with a resistor $r$. The actual voltage that it generates when a current $I$ passes through it is $V(I) = V-Ir$, which is less than its no-load voltage $V$.  $r$ is called the internal resistance of the cell.

We can measure the open circuit potential difference (EMF) of a cell using a potentiometer. We can measure the terminal voltage (potential difference between the terminals of the battery), say by using a voltmeter? Does the difference between the two tell the loss in potential difference due to the internal resistance of the battery? How do we justify the application of Ohm's law to the loss in potential difference due to the internal resistance of the battery? Just to be clear.

@Learner The application of Ohm's law is justified because the "loss" in potential $V - V(I)$ is linear in $I$ to a good approximation. If it were not linear in $I$ then we could not use Ohm's law and we would have to use some more complicated expression.

Thanks for the answers! I am looking for any reference or material that explain this approximation. Is it based on empirical data?

@Learner There are some references in the Wikipedia article on internal resistance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance

Thanks again! The wiki source says that the voltage drop due to internal resistance is equal to the product of I and r. Doesn't say an approximation. It says V (drop) = I.r straight out of Ohm's law.

@gandalf61 we certainly dont need a voltage reference to measure voltage drop.Voltage drop is relative.

The voltage “drop” across a resistor describes the change in electrical potential in moving from the positive terminal to its negative terminal in the circuit. If you move from the negative terminal to the positive terminal of the same resistor it would be called a “rise” in potential.
The potential difference, or voltage, across the resistor is the same regardless of the direction across the resistor.
Hope this helps.


In the famous equation V = IR of Ohm's law, V is the potential difference present between two points

This is only true if the two points are connected by a (ideal, linear) resistor and not by any other devices or current paths.
Ohm's law is an observational law about the nature of certain conductive materials. It isn't a general fact about any two points in space.

But the same equation is also applied to determine the drop in potential difference due to the resistor.

It is only applied to resistors, not to any other devices. There is no "also" --- resistors are the only case where it applies.

Ex: If 'r' is the internal resistance of the battery and the strength of the current is I, then the loss in potential difference due to the internal resistance of the battery is given by I.r.

This isn't a strict use of Ohm's law. It's a statement that you can model a real-world battery as a combination of an ideal battery and a series resistor.
But (if the battery is connected to a load) there's no physical point in space where you could measure a potential equal to the anode potential plus the EMF of the battery. The "point in space" on the side of the "resistor" in the model that isn't exposed to the outside world isn't physical.
We can observe that
$$V = \mathscr{E}-Ir$$
where $V$ is the voltage across the terminals, $\mathscr{E}$ is the emf of the battery, $I$ is the load current, and $r$ is the "equivalent resistance" of the battery. But that doesn't mean there's any physical points inside the battery across which we could measure potentials of $\mathscr{E}$ or $Ir$. The battery behaves as if there was such a resistor inside it, but there is no actual resistor --- just limitations on the rate of the chemical reaction by which the battery produces a potential between its electrodes.

I think in the Ohm's law V stands for the opposing potential ( difference ) produced by the current (I) in the cell due to its internal resistance (r, proportionality constant in Ohm's law). Opposing whatever is causing the current in the first place. In case of a cell it is the EMF (potential difference between the terminals of the cell due to their natural electrode potentials). As per Ohm's law the opposing potential is I.r. As a result there is some loss in emf of the cell, that is expressed by =ℰ−. Not sure if this understanding makes sense.

@Learner, what I'm telling you is that there are no "two points" in space where you can measure this potential difference separate from points where you could measure $\mathscr{E}$. You start out saying that Ohm's law is about the potential difference between "two points" and I'm telling you that this is not what is meant when we talk about the equivalent resistance of a battery.
